# How do you send a message queue from the server side to show up on the client?

Tags: c, client-server, posix, message-queue

```
do {
    printf("+++ ");
    fflush(stdout);

    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
    CHECK(0 <= mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0));

} while (strncmp(buffer, CMD_EXIT, strlen(CMD_EXIT)));
```

this is what I have for the client side to send over to the server side. can I just do something similar with the server side?

Answer (score 1):

For two processes (running on the same machine) to communicate via POSIX message queues, each one opens the queue (where "the" queue is identified by a mutually-agreed name provided to `mq_open()`).  Any message posted to the queue can be retrieved by any process that has it open, by calling `mq_receive()`.  Messages are received in priority order, and oldest-to-youngest among messages having the same priority.

It would be tricky to base a bidirectional communication protocol on a single message queue, but you could do it with two, one for each direction.  Still, that's not really the intended use case for the feature.  You might consider whether a pair of FIFOs would serve you as well as or better than a pair of message queues.